# Issues with keeping session running across page and directing correctly

Tags: php, session

So ive been reading up on it and im still not understanding my issue with keeping a session. I am trying it on two pages right now with a third page handling setting the session.

login.php "where the user logs in"

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['display_name'])) {
    header("Location:userpage.php");
    echo "logged in";
}
else {
    echo"logged out";
}

require_once "createtable.php";
require_once "comments.php";
require_once "Users.php";
?>

<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['messages'])) {
        $sentiment = $_SESSION['sentiment'];
        foreach($_SESSION['messages'] as $message) {
            echo "<div class = 'message $sentiment'>$message</div>";
        }
    }
?>

<?php
 $presets = array();
 if (isset($_SESSION['presets'])) {
   $presets = array_shift($_SESSION['presets']);
 }
 unset($_SESSION['presets']);
 unset($_SESSION['messages']);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type  = "text/css" href = "login.css">
        <title> Login/ Sign up </title>
    </head>
<body>

<h1 class = "title"> Login/Sign up</h1>

<div class ="handles">
<ul class="handles">
<li class="handles"><a class="handles" href="htt[s://www.twitter.com"> <img src="twitter.png" width=100px; height=100px;></a></li> 
<li class="handles"><a class="handles" href="https://www.snapchat.com"> <img src="snapchat.png" width=100px; height=100px;></a></li>
<li class="handles"><a class="handles" href="https://www.instagram.com/"> <img src="instagram.png" width=100px; height=100px;></a></li>
<li class="handles"><a class="handles" href="https://www.twitch.com"> <img src="twitch.png" width=100px; height=100px;></a></li>
<li class="handles"><a class="handles" href="https://www.youtube.com"> <img src="youtube.png" width=100px; height=100px;></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="subMenu"> 
    <ul class = "subMenu">
        <li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "https://ruck64.herokuapp.com/home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "myStory.php">My Story</a></li>  
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "purpose.php">Purpose of PhsyquiesPhunction</a></li> 
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "regimens.php">Regimens/Diet</a></li> 
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "https://www.twitch.tv/">Twitch</a></li> 
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "contact.php">Contact</a></li> 
<li class = "subMenu"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){ ?><a class="subMenu" href="login.php">logout</a>
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu" href="userpage.php">Your Profile</a>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <a class="subMenu" href="login.php">Sign Up/Login</a>
    <?php } ?>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class = "main">
    <div id="wrapperform">
        <div class="form_div">
            <p class="form_label">LOGIN FORM</p>
            <form method="post"  action = "handlerlogin.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                <p><input value = "<?php echo isset($presets['email']) ? $presets['email'] : ''; ?>" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" id = "email" name = "email"></p>
                <p><input type="password" placeholder="Password" id = "password" name = "password"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="LOGIN"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="form_div">
            <p class="form_label">SIGNUP FORM</p>
            <form method="post" action = "handlercreate.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                <p><input value = "<?php echo isset($presets['display_name']) ? $presets['display_name'] : ''; ?>" type="text" placeholder="Enter Display Name" id = "display_name" name = "display_name"></p>
                <p><input value = "<?php echo isset($presets['email']) ? $presets['email'] : ''; ?>" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" id = "email" name = "email"></p>
                <p><input type="password" placeholder="Password" id = "password" name = "password"></p>
                <p><input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id = "confirmpassword" name = "confirmpassword"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="SIGNUP"></p>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
    <!--<script type = "text/javascript" src = "login.js"></script>-->

<div class = "footer">
    This is the footer
</div>  

</body>     


</html>
```

Userpage.php "where it goes if they login in correctly, i did have it automatically forward you to the userpage.php if the password and email was correct but im trying to use sessions now"

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['display_name'])) {
    header("Location:userpage.php");
    echo "logged in";
}
else {
    header("Location:login.php");

}

require_once "createtable.php";
require_once "comments.php";
require_once "Users.php";
require_once "handlerlogin.php"
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> User </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="user.css">
</head>

<h1 class = "title"> User </h1>

<div class ="handles">
<ul class="handles">
<li class="handles"><a class="handles" href="https://www.twitter.com"> <img src="twitter.png" width=100px; height=100px;></a></li> 
<li class="handles"><a class="handles" href="https://www.snapchat.com"> <img src="snapchat.png" width=100px; height=100px;></a></li>
<li class="handles"><a class="handles" href="https://www.instagram.com"> <img src="instagram.png" width=100px; height=100px;></a></li>
<li class="handles"><a class="handles" href="https://www.twitch.com"> <img src="twitch.png" width=100px; height=100px;></a></li>
<li class="handles"><a class="handles" href="https://www.youtube.com"> <img src="youtube.png" width=100px; height=100px;></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="subMenu"> 
<ul class = "subMenu">
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "https://ruck64.herokuapp.com/home.php">Home</a></li>
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "myStory.php">My Story</a></li>  
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "purpose.php">Purpose of PhsyquiesPhunction</a></li> 
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "regimens.php">Regimens/Diet</a></li> 
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "https://www.twitch.tv/">Twitch</a></li> 
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu"  href = "contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
<li class = "subMenu"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){ ?><a class="subMenu" href="logout.php">logout</a>
<li class = "subMenu"><a class = "subMenu" href="userpage.php">Your Profile</a>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <a class="subMenu" href="login.php">Sign Up/Login</a>
    <?php } ?>
</li> 
</ul>
    </div>
  <h2> This is my page. Not yours </h2>


  <div class ="sideBar">
  <p class="shadow ">Welcome User</p>
  <p class ="button"> <a href = "userinfo.html"><input type="button" value="User Info"></p>
  <p class ="button"> <a href = "userpics.html"><input type="button" value="Your pics"></p>
  <p class ="button"> <a href = "editinfo.html"><input type="button" value="Edit Your Info"</p>
  </div>

  <div class = "footer">
This is the footer
    </div>
```

handlerlogin.php "which handles security and tries to set the session"

```
session_start();
require_once 'Users.php';
require_once 'comments.php';
$Users = new Users();

try {
    require "dbconfig.php";
    $conn = new PDO(stuff);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$_SESSION['presets'] = array($_POST);

$valid = true;
$messages = array(); 

if(empty($email)) {
    $messages[] = "Please enter a display name";
    $valid = false;
}

if(empty($password)) {
    $messages[] = "Please enter a password";
    $valid = false;
}

if(!isset($error)){

     $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=?");
    $query->execute(array($_POST['email']));
    if($query->fetchColumn() === $_POST['password']) //better to hash it
    {
        // starts the session created if login info is correct
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['display_name'] = $_POST['display_name'];
        $messages[] = "login successful";
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $valid = false;
        $messages[] = "Email and Password do not match or do not exist";
        header("Location: userpage.php");
        exit;
    }
}
if (!$valid) {
    $_SESSION['sentiment'] = "bad";
    $_SESSION['messages'] = $messages;
    header("Location:login.php");
    exit;
}

    $messages[]="it worked";
    $_SESSION['messages'] = $messages;

exit;
```

Again the issue is it isnt keeping the session, which is set in the handler if they login correctly but its not saving

Comment: [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) required there's to much 'extra' going on here to be able to debug it

Comment: Note, Userpage.php will always do a location change via `header`, so ALL of the content following that first if condition is needless. You should generally put a `session_write_close();` and `exit;` after changing locations with `header`. Unless your spam of code here is not valid, in which case ... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Always do an `exit();` right after `header redirection`  so no other codes will be executed after the redirect.

Comment: I appreciate the feed back. Ill go through and try and see what i can do to remedy the issue.

Comment: I appreciate the feed back. Ill go through and try and see what i can do to remedy the issue.